# How to use Doctrine 2 Command Line Interface from inside a Symfony 2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, console, doctrine-orm

I want to use some features of Doctrine 2 command line interface that Symfony 2 does not enable on app/console.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23234127/4265352).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to add a new Command to your Symfony2 console.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/console.html

But which Doctrine cli feature is missing?