# Enabling Doctrine DBAL commands in Symfony app/console

Tags: symfony, configuration, doctrine-orm, dbal

When using bare-bone Doctrine with the command line that comes out of the box there are two commands available that don't seem to be available with using Doctrine with Symfony and the `app/console`:

```
dbal
  dbal:import    Import SQL file(s) directly to Database.
  dbal:run-sql   Executes arbitrary SQL directly from the command line.
```

Is there a way to enable these commands within Symfony's `app/console`?

Comment: These commands should be available via `bin/doctrine`.

Comment: @kix; I understand that. The problem with `bin/doctrine` is that it doesn't understand the `--env` parameter. I want these commands to be available from `app/console`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, as you may call it that, or maybe rather just a way to enable the commands.

By adding a `Command` to one of your own bundles (or a dedicated one, is up to you), you can simply subclass the Doctrine command. E.g. to enable the `dbal:import` command use the following:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Command\Doctrine;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;

class ImportCommand extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand {

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();

        $doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');

        $em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
        $db = $em->getConnection();

        $helperSet = $this->getHelperSet();
        $helperSet->set( new ConnectionHelper( $db ), 'db' );
        $helperSet->set( new EntityManagerHelper( $em ), 'em' );

        parent::execute( $input, $output );
    }

}
```

As you can see, we simply subclass the original command. Since the database configuration is managed by Symfony we need to get the entity manager through the container. Once we update the `HelperSet` we pass execution back to the parent class.

Answer (score 5):

Put this as `cli-config.php` into your project's root directory. This will enable the `--env` parameter for `php vendor/bin/doctrine`. It is "inspired" by Symfony's app/console file.

Note this is for Doctrine <=2.3, see [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) for newer versions.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/app/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$kernel->boot();

$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

return $helperSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine commands are available in symfony projects through the DoctrineBundle (since version [1.6.4](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/releases/tag/1.6.4)).

You can now run `php bin/console doctrine:database:import [files]`.